Finding normal vector of a surface
How to find normal vector of the slanted surface E shown in the figure?  It would be in the form  $A\hat j + B\hat k$. Please show the steps if you can.
Thanks!

Solution:
I found the method according to this link https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408m/Display12-5-4.shtml.
First, find the vertices of the plane.Three are sufficient.
Let the vertices be:
$P_1 = (1.3,0.5,0)$, $P_2 = (1.3,0,0.7)$ and $P_3 = (0,0,0.7)$,
Take any two vectors on the plane such as:
$ \vec P_{21} = (0,0.5,-0.7)$
$ \vec P_{31} = (1.3,0.5,-0.7)$.
To find the vector of the plane,
consider the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\0 & 0.5 & -0.7 \\1.3 & 0.5 & -0.7\end{bmatrix}
The second and third rows of the matrix are the vectors $\vec P_{21}$ and $\vec P_{31}$.
Evaluating its determinant, we get the vector of the plane as $0.91\hat j + 0.65\hat k.$. Normal of the plane is then $ \frac{0.91}{\sqrt(0.91^2 + 0.65^2}\hat j   + \frac{0.65}{\sqrt(0.91^2 +.65^2}\hat k $.
Normal vector of the plane surface $\hat E$ is $0.814\hat j + 0.581 \hat k$.
The image is copyright of www.danfleisch.com/. Actual location of the pic is at:
https://www.danfleisch.com/maxwell/chapter2/problem3/1a-graph.gif

Can you write an equation for that plane?

Is the equation like ay + bz = c ? I am not sure if its correct.

I am trying this method to find the equation of the plane using its four vertices. https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408m/Display12-5-4.shtml

If the equation of the plane is $ax+by+cz=d$, then a normal vector to the plane is $(a,b,c)$.

Using the method in the above link, I got the equation of the plane as $0.91\hat j+0.65\hat k$.

With that, normal vector of the surface is  $0.814\hat j+0.581\hat k$.

Let the equation of the plane $E$ be $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ Since, the plane passes through the points $(0,0,70)$, $(0,50,0)$, $(130,0,70)$ and $(130,50,0)$, we can put this all together and find that:
$$
70c+d=0\\50b+d=0\\130a+70c+d=0\\130a+50b+d=0
$$
Here, we find $a=0$ and we can consider $d=t$, then $c=-70t$ and $b=-50t$. Therefore, the equation of the plane is $\langle0,-50t,-70t\rangle=t\langle0,-50,-70\rangle$.
For any plane $ax+by+cz=d$, the normal plane is simply the coefficients of the variables $\langle a,b,c\rangle$. The normal vector is then $t(-50\hat{j}-70\hat{k})$ with $t\in \mathbb R$.
